# How can I get the changes from a "master" repository in mercurial for a project hosted on google code?

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I create a "server" clone from a project hosted at code.google.com.  I create a clone from that repository in my machine and push some changes; everything goes well.

Now the master repository has some changes and I want to pull them.  How do I get my "server" clone updated with those changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hg pull -u google_code_url
```

The -u means automatically update your working copy.  You can set (if it's not already there) a default URL in the `.hg/hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
default = pull_url
default-push = push_url
```

Then, you can just do:

```
hg push
hg pull -u
```

Of course, you can still specify a different location manually.

Comment: I also find 'hg summary --remote' extremely useful

Comment: Even if that repository is not where I did my local copy ?  Regular projects are like: http://code.google.com/p/someproject and my "server" clone is http://code.google.com/r/othername So, if I understood correctly doing: `hg pull -u http://code.google.com/p/someproject` will update my local project right?

Comment: @Oscar, yes, you can pull from any clone, and if necessary it will prompt you to merge.

Comment: @Oscar, yes, `hg pull` alone will modify your local repository, but not the actual files in your working copy.  `incoming` doesn't have a `-u`.  In fact, it doesn't ever modify your repository or working directory.  It just tells you what's available.

Comment: Pull by default does not merge. You may get merge prompt if you specified -u and you have uncommitted changes.

Comment: @Geoff, yes, that comment was in reference to the command Oscar posted, which has `-u`.

Comment: I have just reviewed this answer, and I wish I could upvote it again :)